# Capture New opened Tab opened by python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to capture the newly opened tab by the selenium web driver.

1. Getting the option element from website

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

dropdown = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "jumpMenu")

selector = Select(dropdown)

options = selector.options
for index in range(1, len(options)-1):
    element = selector.first_selected_option
    selector.select_by_value("DEIR PDFs/00.DEIR Cover_Kaiser.pdf")
    print(element.text)
```

2. Set the value of the option

```
js = 'value="DEIR PDFs/00.DEIR Cover_Kaiser.pdf"'
driver.execute_script(js)
```

3. Pressing the go button-through executing script which is on `on-click` button

```
js = "MM_jumpMenuGo('jumpMenu','parent',1)"
driver.execute_script(js)
```

4. A new tab is opening here. I want to save/download the new opened webpage

**Re-create the Idea**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


# Installing driver
driver  = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Getting the page
driver.get('https://planning.lacity.org/development-services/eir/kaiser-permanente-los-angeles-medical-center-project-0')

# Getting the drop-down element
dropdown = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "jumpMenu2")

# Selecting the value
js = 'value="DEIR PDFs/00.DEIR Cover_Kaiser.pdf"'
driver.execute_script(js)

# Open new cash
js = "MM_jumpMenuGo('jumpMenu','parent',1)"
driver.execute_script(js)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "capture"? Also, Selenium offers API for getting reference of newly opened tabs and windows. Is that not working out for you? See https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/windows/#windows-and-tabs

Comment: This means I want to get the HTML of the newly opened tab.